# How do delete elements from page based on cookie value?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I want to create a button on my webpage, which when clicked, sets a cookie with a specified value. The cookie should be valid for the entire domain, all its directories and sub-domains.

The code I'm using now is this:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
    {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "name1" + cvalue + "value1" + expires + ";path=/";
    }
```

Then, once the cookie and its value is set, I want that button to get deleted from the page. Also, next time the page loads, I want to check if the cookie and the value exists and if not, show the button or else, delete the button.

The button in context has an id: delete

I'm using this code to check for cookie and its value:

```
function getCookie(name1)
    {
        var name = name1 + "value1";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++)
            {
                var c = ca[i];

                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
                    {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                    }

                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
                    {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
            }

        return "";
    }
```

I've found these codes from here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I'm going to use this code to delete the element if the cookie and its value is present:

```
function removeElement(elementId)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(delete);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
```

I've taken this code from here: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/adding-and-removing-elements-on-the-fly-using-javascript

I don't know how to link those 2 fuctions to carry out the required action.

Comment: does your `getCookie` method return the `id` of the button you want to delete?

Comment: @AmitDas Not, yet.

Comment: Then what is the relation between the `cookie` and the `button` you want to delete?

Comment: @AmitDas Probably, none. That's what I have asked. How do I link those 2 functions.

Comment: Is there a specific button you want to delete? Or are there multiple buttons?

Comment: @AmitDas Just the one with the id 'delete'.

Comment: Ohh ok. I'll type out an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your requirements you just want to delete a specific button if the cookie is present.
In this case you will need to do 2 things.

1. Call the `getCookie` and based on the `return` value call the `removeElement` at the end of the `setCookie` method.

   > Note: I am assuming your `setCookie` method is `synchronous`.
2. Load the `button` by default and do the same as Step 1 once the page is `loaded`.

To summarize, your mrthods should look like this:

`setCookie` method:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "name1" + cvalue + "value1" + expires + ";path=/";
    if(getCookie(cname)) removeElement('delete');
}
```

After Loading the document:

```
document.onload = ()=>{
    if(getCookie(cname)) removeElement('delete');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution for you. Take a look at the comments inside the Code.

Are u new to JS? in this case you should take a look at [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/). Its for free and you will learn the basics very fast.

> Note that SO does not allow you to check or set cookies. For that reason the runable code below will cause an error. Here is [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzva5t2g/1/).

```js
if (getCookie('myCookie')) removeElement('myButton'); // remove if cookie is set

if (document.getElementById('myButton')) document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() { // bind function to clickevent
  setCookie('myCookie', 'myValue', 1); // set cookie
  removeElement('myButton'); // remove button
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) { // your setCookie Funktion
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + '; '+ expires + ";path=/"; // reset to w3schools solution
}

function getCookie(name) { // your getCookie Funktion
  // removed 'var name = ...' because you wont find your cookie if you changing the name here
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];

    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }

    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }

  return "";
}

function removeElement(elementId) { // your removeElement Function
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId); // variable delete was undefined, if your buttons id was delete you had to write it in ''
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton">
  click me
</button>
```